# Converting differents units to numbers

Tags: type-conversion

I'm trying to convert a column of money amount to numeric values. But in the same variable I have
differents units( 9000, 10.1k, 11k ) .How Can I put the "k" with the proper amount of zeros?

I was trying to change the "k" for  "000" but this only  works for 13k or 14k not amounts like
13.1 k

Answer (score 0):

The "k" at the end of numbers stands for multiplication by 1000. So, instead of appending three 0s, you could simply remove the "k" and multiply the number by 1000.

Comment: thank you ! that´s helpful but if you already have more rows with digits without "k" how can I unify everything . Because if I remove the "k" now I have for example 5600 , 22, 13 and I cannot multiply by 100 all the variable